# django receiver - DoesNotExist: WidgetList matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently using `@receiver` to add a token to new users like so -

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

What I also want to be able to do is create a default WidgetList based on this model:

```
class WidgetList(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyAppUser')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class MPTTMEta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

I tried making another reciever -

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_root_list(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        WidgetList.objects.create(user=instance)
```

EDIT - on the initial `python manage.py migrate` I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 226, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 280, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/guardian/management/__init__.py", line 39, in create_anonymous_user
    user.save()
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 771, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/opt/myproject/core/models.py", line 18, in create_root_list
    WidgetList.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/models.py", line 393, in __init__
    super(MPTTModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 480, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

this is the second traceback if I try to rerun migrate:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 87, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_encrypted_lookup/views.py", line 41, in dispatch
    return super(EncryptedLookupGenericViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/opt/myproject/api/serializers.py", line 106, in create
    validated_data['parent'] = WidgetList.objects.get(pk=user_parent_list)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: WidgetList matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Your error happens on `validated_data['parent'] = WidgetList.objects.get(pk=user_parent_list)`, you should check 1. If the record is indeed created by your signal. 2. The value of `user_parent_list` is the value you expected.

Comment: I updated the question I just realized I had the wrong traceback.  I tried running `python manage.py migrate` twice.  first traceback is now included.  in either case no user is created yet so not sure why it fails on the migrate.

Comment: getting somewhere.  I changed `user` to `owner` which was an obvious mistake.  Now on initial migrate I get `django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: WidgetList has no parent.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your traceback and your code, you can find that error happens here:

```
WidgetList.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Your model `WidgetList` doesn't even have `user` field, so it's pretty obvious that you cannot do that. Maybe you were copying & paste the code that caused an error.

Comment: correct. I updated it to `WidgetList.objects.create(owner=instance)` and now get a new error - `django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: WidgetList has no parent.` which makes sense because at migrate the tables are empty

Comment: What does your migration do?

Comment: I got it!  In my testing I changed `null=True, blank=True` in my model I reverted back and it worked!  Will mark this as solved when it lets me!

Comment: Yea I figured. If they are nullable then it won't complaint about this.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no user in your model. Which I see you mean owner.
2. You will get foreign key ref errors as there is not data. Load some parent data using fixture. That would solve this issue.